# gdalwarp not clipping VRT to correct extent

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, vrt

I'm trying to clip a projected .vrt raster to an extent expressed in GCS coordinates and it's not doing what I would expect. Here is my command:

```
gdalwarp -te -133.08813624 56.69042536 -132.69405069 56.93121339 -te_srs EPSG:4326 -tr 30 30 input_DEM.vrt clipped_DEM.tif
```

However the output coordinates of the clipped_DEM.tif are:
-133.181430831 56.6899107291 -132.601585159 56.9311731495

This doesn't seem like much, but it's enough to completely throw off my process as I need a DEM to completely cover a certain extent (the polygon featured in the screenshot below). The clipped DEM, also seen below, should actually completely surround the polygon with a little bit (0.05 degrees) of padding. Instead it appears the clip's extent is stretched extra to the left and right, but cut off from the top and bottom. I've pulled the .vrt into Arc to look at it and it definitely has data (way) beyond the resulting extent.

I've used the same exact process before, only the raster I was clipping was a (projected) .tif, not a (projected) .vrt. As a result I'm thinking the latter has something to do with it. For now I can make my process work by adding 0.5 degrees to the edges instead of just 0.05 degrees, but I would like to know why this is occurring as I will need to further develop this process in the future.[image: DEM clip error]

Comment: Can you add the CRS? I guess you run into problems because the target extent CRS is different from the raster's CRS.

Comment: Have you tried to give the -te in the target srs units and without -te_srs?

Comment: If the given rectangle ends up being tilted in the raster's ProjCRS, it will be "reboxed". Looking at your polygon example, you're only giving it the left and right corners, so that the upper and lower extents are getting clipped, and the left-right extent is larger than you expect.

Comment: @user30184 I have not because I don't know how to convert the GCS extent into the projected extent, which is why the -te_srs feature was so necessary

Comment: @AndreJ The raster is in Canada Albers and the polygon is in GCS. I know the extent I want the clipped raster to have, but only in terms of GCS and not Albers. Which is why I used the -te_srs option. I have used the same or very similar command before but using a tiff raster not a vrt. I don't know why it would work for .tifs and not vrts but maybe that's what my problem is?